# How do I create a table-per-class mapping with fluent nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, table-per-class

I'm trying to create a mapping similar to the following with fluent nhibernate:

```
<class name="IAccountManager" 
    abstract="true" 
    table="IAccountManager">

    <id name="Id">
            <generator class="hilo"/>
    </id>

    <union-subclass
            table="DefaultAccountManager"
            name="DefaultAccountManager">
            <property name="FirstName"/>
    </union-subclass>

    ... more subclasses
</class>
```

Thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union-subclasses currently aren't supported by Fluent NHibernate. FNH allows you to mix fluent and hbm mappings, so you should keep the hbm mappings for this case.

Comment: :( I'll have to look into submitting a patch. I'm using the HbmMappings feature of fluent NHibernate now. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. Thanks.